# Three.js textured objects disappear when adding some other objects to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am rendering points in a way derived from the following example:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_points

i.e. I use points that are textured using a disc.png image through buffer geometry.

However, when I add some more objects to the scene (lines in this particular example), the textured points disappear. If I remove those objects from the scene, the textured points reappear.

The behavior of the disappearence is unpredictable: they sometimes display properly, and sometimes they don't. If I generate an object from one place in code, adding that object causes the textured points to disappear, but if I generate it in the exactly same way from another place in the code, everything works nicely.

As in the original example, the points themselves are created using the following code:

```
obj.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
            color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
            texture: { type: "t", value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/disc.png') }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
        alphaTest: 0.9
});
obj.geometry = geometryFromCoordinates([[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ...]);
obj.mesh = new THREE.Points(obj.geometry, obj.material);
```

where `geometryFromCoordinates` is defined as

```
function geometryFromCoordinates (coordinates, building) {
    var helper = geometryFromArray(coordinates);
    var positions = new Float32Array(3 * coordinates.length);
    var colors = new Float32Array(3 * coordinates.length);
    var sizes = new Float32Array(coordinates.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
        var vertex = helper.vertices[i];
        vertex.toArray(positions, 3*i);
        MESH.NODE_COLOR.NORMAL.toArray(colors, i*3);
        sizes[i] = MESH.NODE_SIZE.NORMAL;
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
    geometry.addAttribute('customColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.addAttribute('size', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sizes, 1));

    return geometry;
};
```

and the `geometryFromArray` helper is given by

```
function geometryFromArray(vertices) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
        var v = vertices[i];
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v[0], v[2], v[1]));
    }
    return geometry;
};
```

The shaders are provided in the header of the html document, just as in the original example:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
attribute float size;
attribute vec3 customColor;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() {
  vColor = customColor;
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
  gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
  if ( gl_FragColor.a < ALPHATEST ) discard;
}
</script>
```

The wireframe objects that I add to a scene are generated using the `box` and `wireframe` functions:

```
function wireframe(vertices) {
    var wireframe = {};
    wireframe.geometry = geometryFromArray(vertices);
    wireframe.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0x777777});
    wireframe.mesh = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframe.geometry, wireframe.material);
    return wireframe;
};

function box(X, Y, Z, W, D, H) {
    return [
        [ X , Y , Z ], [ X , Y ,Z+H],
        [ X , Y ,Z+H], [ X ,Y+D,Z+H],
        [ X ,Y+D,Z+H], [ X ,Y+D, Z ],
        [ X ,Y+D, Z ], [ X , Y , Z ],

        [X+W, Y , Z ], [X+W, Y ,Z+H],
        [X+W, Y ,Z+H], [X+W,Y+D,Z+H],
        [X+W,Y+D,Z+H], [X+W,Y+D, Z ],
        [X+W,Y+D, Z ], [X+W, Y , Z ],

        [ X , Y , Z ], [X+W, Y , Z ],
        [ X ,Y+D, Z ], [X+W,Y+D, Z ],
        [ X , Y ,Z+H], [X+W, Y ,Z+H],
        [ X ,Y+D,Z+H], [X+W,Y+D,Z+H]
    ];
};
```

I generate a lot of boxes that way, and join their coordinates using `Array.concat`, and then I pass them on to the `wireframe` function, and then I invoke `scene.add`:

```
var vetices = [];
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; ++i) {
    var b = boxes[i];
    vertices.concat(box(b.x, b.y, b.z, b.w, b.d, b.h));
}
var skeleton = wireframe(vertices);
scene.add(skeleton.mesh);
```

Could someone explain what could be a possible reason for this misbehavior and how to find a workaround? As I mentioned earler, the reproduction of the bug is unpredictable, and the code that has been working for me for a couple of months suddenly stopped to work, although I haven't made any changes to it.

Also, I don't need to use textures, if I could render clickable circles or spheres some other way -- but I would need some suggestions, as I know very little about WebGL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code you have so far, preferably with problematic lines indicated as such?

Comment: @DaanMeijer I just did extract the essential parts. However, the bug is rather diffincult to reproduce, so I don't expect the problem to be in the code.

Comment: (Without looking at it much at all) It may be because your points lie on a surface, and are being hidden -- like they are INSIDE something.